# claims authentication

Tags: claims-based-auth

We are using claims authentication which means sp-sts authenticates the user. we have a custom membership provider that authenticates but we want to change the username. we tried setting the name claim and the SPLogonUser claim in our claims provider but that doesn't work...what is the way to set the name claim for SP-STS?

So basically, the user logons to the site, sts validates the user, now we have to change to username, and we tried to add nameidentifier claim, but apparently sharepoint adds this claim again, and it throws exception for duplicate claims

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you wrote a membership provider using the ASP.NET Membership provider interface, and that provider is configured on a SharePoint 2010 web application.

That interface has a username property which you should use to return the unique value that identifies the user.

Also, the SharePoint STS *never* performs authentication. It only issues tokens to represent the current user to other SP services.

Comment: here is my problem, maybe I was not clear before:
We are using Claims Authentication for SharePoint 2010. That means users are authenticated via SharePoint STS and the configured membership provider. We have a situation where the username passed to the membership provider is NOT the username we want returned to SHarePoint to uniquely identify the user's profile. This makes it impossible for users to authenticate in different ways such as using an alternate username/password yet being treated as the same user, or using a session id from Site Minder. How can I change this username after login?